# How do I do experiments of blockchain consensus algorithms

Tags: blockchain, consensus

I'm writing a paper on the blockchain consensus algorithm. How should I experiment?

or How do I do the simulation experiment of the blockchain consensus algorithm

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing simulation experiment of the blockchain consensus algorithm is by writing code. There are many ways of achieving consensus in a Blockchain. Proof of Work(PoW) is one of the most popular ways to achieve consensus. An example of PoW consensus that I have used in Blockchain is: "A block will not be created unless its hash key starts with four consecutive “3”s." I have used Python code to achieve this. I have written a blog post and a simple working application (Blockchain) with end-to-end working Python code on GitHub with this PoW consensus. Please check: http://softwaredevelopercentral.blogspot.com/2020/07/blockchain-and-cryptocurrency-tutorial.html